# Extract found word and 20 Words before and after it

Tags: r, text-mining

I am using stringr to scan through a very long text. If the word is found. I want to extract not only the word, but some context, lets say twenty words before and after the word has been detected.

So If I have "Hello there, how are you?" and I look for "there", I want to extract there +-1 Word:
"Hello there, how"

However, I am having problems in combining str_locate and str_word since one expresses location as the character-number and the other works with the word-number

How do I go about this? I know how to locate a word and I know how to extract words. But How do I extract words around a specific word?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

text <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."

# Lets say I am looking for "sit"

str_locate_all(text,"sit") # I get the positions for "sit" ... but expressed in the number of letters


# assuming sit-position is expressed as  word-number and not character number
sit_position <- c(4,20,30,40)  # not the real positions of "sit" just to simulate


#the word plus minus two 
sit_position_d <- sit_position-2
sit_position_u <- sit_position+2

wordcontext <- rep(NA,NROW(sit_position))

for (i in c(1:NROW(sit_position))) {

  wordcontext[i] <- word(text, sit_position_d[i],sit_position_u[i])


}
```

How do I change this code to tell word() that it needs to start from a specific word?

Comment: the output for given example should be `dolor sit amet` no ?

Comment: Yes. I think it appears three times in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this with `stringr` as you started, you can use an expression like the one below.  To make it easier to check, I just took up to 6 word on either side,  but it should be easy to change this to 20 words.

```
str_extract(text, "(\\w+\\W+){0,6}sit(\\W+\\w+){0,6}")
[1] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"
```

**Details**

The expression is centered on the word that you want to find, in this case "sit".
`(\\w+\\W+){0,6}` matches up to 6 words before "sit".
`(\\W+\\w+){0,6}` matches up to 6 words after "sit".

Comment: This works! Thank you very much. I read a bit about regex while waiting for an answer and also added 
w+(\\.|,|;|:|\\!|\\?|-|_)?\\s+){1,20}
to include special characters.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of task is better suited for text-mining packages. For example quanteda has a function called `kwic` which does what you want. If you don't use the `remove_punct` the punctuation would be counted as a word. And you can easily transform the results in a nice data.frame.

```
library(quanteda)
my_kwic <- kwic(text, "sit", window = 6, remove_punct = TRUE)

  [text1, 4]                      Lorem ipsum dolor | sit | amet consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam
 [text1, 49] takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor | sit | amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet          
 [text1, 54]       dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor | sit | amet consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam
 [text1, 99] takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor | sit | amet    

my_df <- data.frame(my_kwic)

  docname from to                                    pre keyword                                      post
1   text1    4  4                      Lorem ipsum dolor     sit amet consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam
2   text1   49 49 takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor     sit           amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
3   text1   54 54       dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor     sit amet consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam
4   text1   99 99 takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor     sit                                      amet
```

Comment: Okay. Wow THANK you. I implemented the solution above. It was calculationg for 10+ hours. I just gave up. A small modification to the function you provided gave me a solution in two minutes. Thank you so much!